# How can I check if there is a signature associated with a deb package?

Tags: security, dpkg, deb, signature

In rpm-based systems, we can easily see if there is a signature associated with an rpm file:

```
rpm -qpi <rpm-file.rpm> | grep -i signature
```

For .deb files, we can see the package information but it doesn't include the information of whether a signature is associated or not:

```
dpkg-deb -I uma-18feb-latest.deb
```

Is there a way in Ubuntu to see the signature without using the following command which actually verifies the signature?

```
dpkg-sig --verify <deb-file.deb>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dpkg-sig --list <deb-file.deb>
```

will list any items in the file which look like a signature, without verifying the file. This will list the role of any signature in the file; *e.g.*

```
$ dpkg-sig -l vuescan_9.7.50-1_amd64.deb
Processing vuescan_9.7.50-1_amd64.deb...
builder
$ dpkg-sig -l zstd_1.4.8+dfsg-2.1_i386.deb
Processing zstd_1.4.8+dfsg-2.1_i386.deb...
$
```

The first file has a signature with the “builder” role; the second file isn’t signed.

Note that it’s unusual for individual `.deb` files to be signed (unlike RPMs). Debian packages’ authenticity relies on the repository’s authenticity; see [How is the authenticity of Debian packages guaranteed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/285635/86440)

Comment: This helped me to check if there is a signature associated with the .deb file. To verify "$?" equals 0 when there is no signature.

Comment: Is there a way to verify if the package contains a signature in vanilla Ubuntu without installing anything like *dpkg-sig* ? Basically where the user does not have sudo permission and can't install anything.

Comment: Yes, `ar -x package.deb` will list the files in raw archive, and signed packages will have files starting with `_gpg`.

Comment: I'd recommend against dpkg-sig, which is not part of the dpkg tool suite, nor supported by it. The ones supported by dpkg are debsigs and debsig-verify. But those still need to get modified to use a different signature layout so that such signed packages could get accepted in the Debian archive (where they are currently being rejected). See https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/Spec/DebSignatures for a draft.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that for `.deb` packages, the entire repository should be signed, i.e. `Release.gpg` file, individual packages can be signed too

```
for i in *.deb; do
    ar -p "$i" _gpgbuilder 2>/dev/null | grep "^Signer";
done
```