# How to verify if a given package is built in a reproducible way as an end user?

Tags: debian, reproducible-build

Let's I would like to verify if the package `mksh` can be built in a reproducible way. I am trying with

```
apt build-dep mksh
apt source mksh
cd mksh; dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
cd ..; sha256sum <freshly build dep>
```

If I now do

```
apt download mksh
```

and compare the checksum of the downloaded deb with the debian package I created locally, the checksum differs (expected as I did not sign the deb)

How to make those checksums match ?

Comment: Typically in Debian, you don't sign the DEB package directly but the APT archive manifests instead, so the checksums on the package itself won't differ for that reason.  However, for a reproducible build, you need to use exactly the same versions of the packages as the original builder used.

Answer (score 4):

[The `mksh` source package builds reproducibly](https://tests.reproducible-builds.org/debian/rb-pkg/unstable/amd64/mksh.html), which means that it would be possible to recreate a given `.deb` package if you can reproduce its build environment. That information is stored [in `.buildinfo` files](https://wiki.debian.org/ReproducibleBuilds/BuildinfoFiles), and with the help of [Debian snapshots](https://snapshot.debian.org), it is possible to retrieve the exact versions of all the packages used to build a given `.deb`.

Currently, [`.buildinfo` files aren’t published alongside binary packages in the Debian repositories](https://bugs.debian.org/763822), but [they are published](https://bugs.debian.org/862073) on [buildinfos.debian.net](https://buildinfos.debian.net/buildinfo-pool/), and this has the `.buildinfo` files for the version of `mksh` currently in Debian 11 (*e.g.* [the `amd64` version](https://buildinfos.debian.net/buildinfo-pool/m/mksh/mksh_59c-9+b2_amd64.buildinfo)). Using that, you can determine what the build environment for a given `mksh` binary package was, and then try reproduce it.

There’s another subtlety here — the current `mksh` package in Debian 11 is a binNMU, whose source doesn’t *exactly* match the published package source. To reproduce the existing binary package, you’d have to include the additional binNMU `changelog` (*e.g.* `changelog.Debian.amd64.gz` in the `amd64` package) with the same contents:

```
mksh (59c-9+b2) sid; urgency=low, binary-only=yes

  * Binary-only non-maintainer upload for amd64; no source changes.
  * Rebuild for outdated Built-Using

 -- amd64 / i386 Build Daemon (x86-ubc-01) <buildd_amd64-x86-ubc-01@buildd.debian.org>  Thu, 05 Aug 2021 11:52:19 +0000
```

Note that if you *can* reproduce a given build environment, the resulting `.deb` files should be exactly identical — binary packages published in Debian aren’t signed themselves, [it’s the metadata describing them that is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/285635/86440).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The underlying data differs, therefore the computed checksum will differ. Finding 2 values thar have the same checksum is a Hard Problem.